# Erro no código de arquivo. c

Tags: c, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca

Preciso fazer um mecanismo de pesquisa simples. Apenas abrir um `arquivo.txt`, procurar uma palavra desejada pelo usuário, verificar quantas vezes uma palavra aparece no arquivo e se ela existe no arquivo. Porém esta dando um erro que não identifiquei a origem, semelhante a ausência do `&`. Segue meu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 500
int main(){
char pprocurada[100];
char *buff[500];
int contpp=0;
FILE *arq;
arq=fopen("C:\\Users\\jvict_000\\Desktop\\JoaoVictorF\\FaroesteCaboclo.txt", "r");
if(arq==NULL)
    printf("n%co foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n",132);
printf("Digite a palavra a ser pesquisada\n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(pprocurada);
fflush(stdin);
fgets(*buff,max,arq);
while (!feof(arq)) {
    if(contpp==0) {
        strtok(*buff," ");
        if(strcmp(pprocurada,*buff)==0)
            contpp++;
    } else {
        strtok(NULL," ");
        if(strcmp(pprocurada,*buff)==0)
            contpp++;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(*buff,max,arq);
}
fclose(arq);
if(contpp!=0)
    printf("Pesquisa terminada, a palavra %s foi encontrada: %d vezes",pprocurada,contpp);
else {
    printf("A palavra %s n%co foi encontrada no arquivo",pprocurada,132);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante informar a mensagem de erro também.

Comment: Ele diz que meu programa executável parou de funcionar.

Comment: Ele roda até pedir a palavra desejada, quando a coloco, ele diz "arquivo.exe parou de funcionar"

Comment: Quando está `debugando`não consegue capturar o erro?

Comment: Não ... :/ Não encontra solução para o problema

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a variável `buff` é definida como um *array de 500 elementos de strings*, onde string == ponteiro para char (`char *`) - mas esses ponteiros estão apontando para endereços arbitrários da memória.

Se você quer declarar uma string com 500 caracteres, mude a declaração para

```
char buff[MAX]; // é convenção declarar constantes/macros em MAIUSCULAS
```

Já que isso declara uma string (`char *`) com tamanho 500 alocados na pilha. E quando for usar essa variável (nas chamadas a `fgets`, `strcmp` e `strtok`), você não precisa dereferenciar o ponteiro, pode usá-la diretamente:

```
fgets(buff,MAX,arq);
```

Isso vai resolver o seu problema da aplicação parar de funcionar. Há outros erros de lógica (na chamada ao `strtok`, por exemplo), que você ainda precisa consertar antes de ter o programa funcionando. Mas use um *debugger* que você vai conseguir ver o erro mais fácil.